# Yii2: Detect Pjax form submit vs manual submit

Tags: jquery, yii2, pjax, active-form

I have a view for creating an item. In the view I have an `ActiveForm` inside `Pjax` this form is an image upload input that upon change I use javascript to submit the form:

```
$('#itemForm').submit();
```

The purpose is that I want to upload the images to a temp folder and display them on the page so they can be sorted before the item is saved.

The problem I have is differentiating between the javascript submit and when the user submits the form by using the submit button.

I've tried adding a name to the submit button:

```
Html::submitButton('Save Item', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'submitButton'])
```

But regardless of if I submit via javascript or via the button, `$_POST` contains `submitButton`, so I can't tell when the images are being uploaded and when the item is being saved.

Comment: Use an hidden field filled when clicked on submit button

Comment: why not post an extra variable with the javasacript call like `is_js` and check it.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That was my first thought. I'm not sure how to do that without breaking the Yii2 pjax though. If this was vanilla php I wouldn't have an issue.

Comment: as FabrizioCaldarelli said, i would say that you should add a hidden field that should be submitted along with the form and when you have to submit the form via js , first populate that hidden field with some value say `1` and then call the `.submit()` and on the php side check the value if its `1` then its `js` submit otherwise normal . how about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to detect the submit via javascript you should declare a hidden field with a default value of `0`.

```
Html::hiddenInput('is_js_submit',0,['id'=>'is_js_submit']);
```

Then before you are calling the

```
$('#itemForm').submit();
```

to submit the form on image upload add the statement

```
$("#is_js_submit").val(1)
```

and now you can check for the value inside your **`controller/action`** if it is a javascript submit or normal form submit.

Hope it helps you out.